# UNIQUE constraint failed: Usuarios.Id (Sqlite code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Tengo una app en android studio en la cual creé un bd sqlite, se supone que el registro ya esta insertado, entonces porque al hacer la consulta sigue entrando al If.

Esta consulta la hago para registrar usuarios, el campo Id lo definí como integer primary key unique, entonces antes de insertarlo revisa que no exista pero siempre entra al if.

```html
 bd = con.getReadableDatabase();
String query = "Select * from " + Utilidades.Users + " where Nombre= '" + _user.getText() + "' and Clave='"+_pass.getText()+"'" ;
Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(query, null);

if (cursor.getCount()==0)
{
  bd.close();
  bd = con.getWritableDatabase();
  con.insertUsuario(Nombre,Clave,Completo,correo,Id);
  bd.close();
}

cursor.close();
bd.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema aquì es que el campo `Id` de tu tabla `Usuarios` tiene una restricciòn, esta definido como [Clave primaria (`PRYMARY_KEY`)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_primaria), este campo no puede ser insertado si existe un registro con el mismo valor, por lo tanto aquì se provoca el problema:

```
con.insertUsuario(Nombre,Clave,Completo,correo,Id);
```

posiblemente esta declarado como `AUTOINCREMENT` , modifica tu mètodo `insertUsuario()` para que ùnicamente inserte los demàs valores a excepciòn de `Id`.